# Why is the pointer declared in main() not changed?

Tags: c++, pointers

I know **call by pointers** in which we pass address of variables.Something like this:

```
void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
   int temp;
   temp = *x; /* save the value at address x */
   *x = *y; /* put y into x */
   *y = temp; /* put x into y */

   return;
}

  swap(&a, &b);
```

And also **call by reference**,in both of these methods the changes made in the function are reflected in actual arguments' variable.
But why are actual parameters passed in this case of call not changed:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void foo(int* c){
c=c+1;
}
int main()
{
    int a=5;
    int *c=&a;
    cout<<&c<<endl; //0x7ffe1a74f3b0
    foo(c);        
    cout<<*c<<endl;//5
    cout<<&c<<endl;//0x7ffe1a74f3b0
}
```

Here c passed to foo() is address of a.So how this is call by value.
Here **c** should have printed garbage value according to me.Please explain what has happened here.

Comment: `foo()`'s parameter is passed by value. Which means that `c=c+1` modifies foo's parameter. That's it. It does nothing to the completely different variable named `c` in `main()`. The End.

Comment: How come it is value? c contains the addr of a.

Comment: A pointer is part of the type of something. An `int*` is not the same as an `int**` which is not the same as an `int***`. You passed the pointer by value. If you assign to it with `*c = value`, obviously that will be reflected in the caller, but changing the value of *c* will not have any effect. There is a distinction between changing the value of `c` and changing the value of what `c` *points* to.

Comment: When you call `foo`, its parameter `c` is set to the address of `a`. Then the line `c=c+1;` sets `c` to be equal to an address that is one past the address of `a`. When `foo` returns, its parameter `c` is discarded and the different variable `c` that is defined within `main` is not affected in any way.

Perhaps you meant to write `*c = *c + 1;` instead?

Comment: @DavidScarlett no,i meant c=c+1; and i was thinking it should change the address of c in main

Comment: @user7098526 Then you need to pass the variable `c` that is defined in main by reference, otherwise the parameter `c` will merely be a copy of it. I'll post an answer to illustrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And also call by reference, in both of these methods the changes made in the function are reflected in actual arguments' variable.

There is an important difference, though: the changes are always made to whatever is referenced/pointed to, never to the reference/pointer itself (modifying a reference is impossible in general).

That is why assigning `c` a new value inside `foo` has no effect on `c` outside `foo`: the pointer passed to a function is *copied*.

If you need to modify the pointer, you need to add another level of dereference by passing a pointer reference or a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from comments, the variable `c` defined in function `main` is a different variable to the parameter `c` of function `foo`. If you want `foo` to be able to modify main's `c`, that is modify the address that `c`'s pointer type holds, then you need to pass either a reference or pointer to `c` to the function instead.

Here is an example that shows the difference between passing `c` by value (as `int *`), or by reference (as `int **` or `int *&`). Don't be fooled by the fact that `int *` is a pointer type, that means that it can receive an `int` by reference or an `int *` by value. And since main's `c` is `int *` rather than `int`, main `c` is being passed by value.

Note the differences in how the functions are called (whether `c` needs the address operator `&` in the function call) and the outcome of each function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo_int_ptr(int* c)
{
    c=c+1;
}

void foo_int_ptr_ptr(int** c)
{
    *c=*c+1;
}

void foo_int_ptr_ref(int*& c)
{
    c=c+1;
}

int main()
{
    int a=5;
    int *c=&a;
    cout << "&c=" << &c << ", c=" << c << ", *c=" << (c==&a ? std::to_string(*c) : std::string("INVALID PTR")) << endl;
    foo_int_ptr(c);
    cout << "&c=" << &c << ", c=" << c << ", *c=" << (c==&a ? std::to_string(*c) : std::string("INVALID PTR")) << endl;
    foo_int_ptr_ptr(&c);
    cout << "&c=" << &c << ", c=" << c << ", *c=" << (c==&a ? std::to_string(*c) : std::string("INVALID PTR")) << endl;
    foo_int_ptr_ref(c);
    cout << "&c=" << &c << ", c=" << c << ", *c=" << (c==&a ? std::to_string(*c) : std::string("INVALID PTR")) << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
&c=0x7e02d81808b8, c=0x7e02d81808ac, *c=5
&c=0x7e02d81808b8, c=0x7e02d81808ac, *c=5
&c=0x7e02d81808b8, c=0x7e02d81808b0, *c=INVALID PTR
&c=0x7e02d81808b8, c=0x7e02d81808b4, *c=INVALID PTR
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a mistake in your thinking about this ..

```
int *c = &a;
```

this doesn't mean that c "contains" address of a, this means that c is a pointer TO the address of a. Passing a pointer to foo() will not do anything.

Comment: Actually, `c` does contain the address of `a`, and `c` *is* a pointer to `a`. But when passed to `foo`, `foo` receives a *copy* of the address of `a` in a new pointer variable.